# Azure APIM Developer Portal page access without authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-api-management

I have a basic authentication in the developer portal of my APIM in azure.
If I go directly (without authenticating) to https://...apimanagementdev.developer.azure-api.net/apis, the page loads.
How can I force pages to load only for authenticated users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to identities => settings and then check Redirect anonymous users to sign-in page

[image]

Comment: Do not forget to clear your browser cache, cockies and so on